# IP camera OMXplayer

Tags: omxplayer

I got an rtsp stream working for an IP camera and was wondering how I make it so it WONT display the date and time at the top of the video and the name of the camera in the bottom right corner of the video.

Comment: Is the camera name added by the camera, the feed or omxplayer?

Comment: the camera, in omxplayer i have written omxplayer --vol 1000 --live rtsp://...../

Comment: Then you need to change it in the camera, which you have not even told us what type you have, however that is irrelevant because it means your question is off-topic.

Comment: I agree with @SteveRobillard here; none of my official Pi cameras do this (I have four currently active), so it's a function of the camera and how it streams which is not related to the Pi.

Comment: I got it, it was through the camera settings

Comment: Please answer your own question to finish it.